# Does disabling HTTP caching affect Service Worker caching?

Tags: http, web, service-worker

I have placed a Service Worker on my page that caches what needs to be cached.

But unfortunately, Firefox will still attempt to cache pages that I didn't tell it to(Eg. feed.xml). This breaks the rss feed in firefox until the page is full refreshed(CTRL + F5).

I assume that this happens because of HTTP Caching, so I wan't to disable HTTP caching via HTML4 tags.

Will my service worker still work properly after doing this?

EDIT:

Here's the link to my page: https://lumpbloom7.github.io

Here's the sw.js code: https://lumpbloom7.github.io/sw.js

Here's the RSS feed: https://lumpbloom7.github.io/feed.xml

Comment: Can you show us some code please?  At least the SW code.  We are debugging blind here.

Comment: I've added links into the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling HTTP cache might solve the caching issue in FF.  But basing from your SW script, there is no event that handles new updates so that it "clears and resets" your cached version.  I would suggest that every time you update your feed.xml, update your service worker as well.  Look at how Google does it [here](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/samples/blob/gh-pages/service-worker/prefetch/service-worker.js).  You would see that there is a `CACHE_VERSION` variable there.  Update that number every time you update your site, whether it may be styling, functionality or the smallest content change.

Comment: Thanks. I managed to stop HTTP caching without affecting service worker functionality. But the feed.xml page still doesn't load properly on FF. 
But since this question is technically solved, I'll put a checker on your answer.